# Elements being blocked by tabLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

Elements of fragments are getting blocked by the tabLayout on the top and I cannot seem to keep the elements below the tabs.

Each tab is it's own fragment.

Any help getting the elements to stick below the tabs is appreciated

[image]

MainActivity.XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:label="Journal Entry"

    tools:context="edu.tp.sghealthapp.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tab">
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/layout_tabbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#339999"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode ="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

fragment_glucoseEntry.XML

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="edu.tp.sghealthapp.GlucoseFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TableLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
            android:gravity="top">


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/titlet"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:text="Glucose Measurement"

                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/glucoseET"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Enter glucose reading (mmol/dl)"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/glucoseTimeTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:text="Time of Glucose Measurement"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/glucoseTimeET"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="Select time..."
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:onClick="onClickShowTimeDialogue" />


            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/glucoseDateTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:text="Date of Glucose Measurement"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />




                </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/glucoseDateET"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="Select Date..."
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:onClick="onClickShowTimeDialogue" />


            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="20dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:onClick="returnHomeOnClick"
                    android:text="Cancel" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSaveEntry"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            </TableRow>



        </TableLayout>


    </FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Toolbar mToolBar;
        TabLayout mTabLayout;
        ViewPager mViewPager;
        Button mBtnSaveEntry;
        EditText mGlucose, mGlucoseTime, mMealTime;
        TableRow t1;
        AutoCompleteTextView mTxtFood, mTxtFood2, mTxtFood3;
        RadioGroup mRadioGrp;
        RadioButton mSelectedRadio;
        Helper helper = new Helper();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry);
            this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);


            mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tabBar);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
            mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            ViewPagerAdapter pgAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            pgAdapter.addFragments( new GlucoseFragment(), "Glucose Entry");
            pgAdapter.addFragments(new FoodEntryFragment(), "Food Entry");
            mViewPager.setAdapter(pgAdapter);
            mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        }
```

GlucoseFragment.java

```
    public class GlucoseFragment extends Fragment {


        public GlucoseFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_glucose, container, false);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Align ViewPager below the AppBarLayout. As you use the relative layout ,You need to add a line in viewPager properies i.e. android:layout_below="@+id/tab"

Comment: You should never use @+id/tab to refer a widget, use @id/tab instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` as alternative to `RelativeLayout` Then add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your viewpager

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

....
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the viewpager alignment which is causing this problem. try and change it to this.

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
          android:layout_below="@id/tablayout"

></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Hope it works. ThankYou